# Show that $e^{-x^2}$ Vanishes at Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is it true that the  function $e^{-x^2}$ is vanishing as $x \to \infty$?
If yes, how do I give such an argument.

Comment: Use taylor expansion of the exponential function

Answer (score 5):

$-x^2$ goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to \infty$. So
$$\exp(-x^2) \to \exp (-\infty) = 0$$
intuitively. Or else, if you know that $ \exp (x) $ grows rapidly when $ x $ is large enough, then
$$\exp(-x^2) =e^{-x^2} = \frac{1}{e^{x^2}}\to 0$$

Answer (score 4):

$e^{x^{2}} >1+\frac {x^{4}} {2!} \to \infty$ so $e^{-x^{2}} =\frac 1 {e^{x^{2}}} \to 0$.

Comment: this works nicely too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and let's try proving the limit at infinity using minimum knowledge about exponential:

- $e^0=1$
- $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$
- $(e^x)'=e^x$

All obtainable from the power series definition of exponential.

$f$ is an even function so we can restrict the study to positive reals.

From $1=e^0=e^ue^{-u}$ you get $\forall u,\ e^u>0$ and so $f'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2}\le 0$ on $[0,+\infty[$.

$f$ is $\searrow$ and bounded inferiorly by $0$ so it has a limit $\ell$ at infinity.

Yet the morphism formula $f(x)=f(\frac x{\sqrt{2}})f(\frac x{\sqrt{2}})$ gives $\ell=\ell^2$ at infinity.

So $\ell=0$ or $1$.

But it cannot be $1$ since $f(0)=1$ and decreasing.

Thus $\ell=0$ and we have proved our result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove it formally, use the [epsilon-delta definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) of the limit. That is, given an arbitrary error bound $\varepsilon > 0$, provide an $x$ such that for all $y > x$, $|\exp(-y^2)| < \varepsilon$ is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-x^{2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{x^{2}}} = 0. $$

Answer (score 0):

(1).By the Binomial Theorem, or by Induction on $n,$ if $A> 0$ and $0\le n\in \Bbb Z $ then $(1+A)^n\ge 1+nA.$

(2).If $A>0$ and  $0\le U\le V$ and then $(1+A)^U\le (1+A)^V.$

(3). Let $[x^2]$ denote the largest  integer not exceeding $x^2$. We have (i)  $x^2\ge[x^2]>x^2-1$ and we have (ii) $[x^2]\ge 0.$

We have $e-1>0.$

Now $e^{x^2} \ge e^{[x^2]}$ by (2)  with $A=e-1$ and $U=[x^2]$ and $V=x^2$, and by (3).

And $e^{[x^2]}\ge 1+[x^2](e-1)$ by (1) with $A=e-1$ and $n=[x^2]$, and by (3)(ii).

And $1+[x^2](e-1)> 1+(x^2-1)(e-1)$ by (3)(i).

Therefore $$|x|>1 \implies  e^{x^2}>1+(x^2-1)(e-1)>(x^2-1)(e-1)>0\implies$$ 
 $$\implies 0<e^{-x^2}<\frac {1}{(x^2-1)(e-1)}.$$

Note that we can obtain the same result if we replace $e$ with any number $>1.$